# Cannot shutdown a shutdown connection MySQL Enterprise Monitor

Tags: mysql, windows, shutdown

We are facing below errors on MySQL Enterprise Monitor.. While deleting a connection from MySQL Instances it is displaying following error messages. 
Also it is not deleted event it displays success message.

> Cannot shutdown a shutdown connection
>   Connection refused: connect

Any way of doing this? Any table in DB storing information in MySQL databases.

MySQL 5.6.21
Windows Platform

Comment: Is this ongoing? What are you trying to kill?

Comment: I am trying to remove a mysql connection from MySQL Enterprise Monitor

Comment: To be honest, this is nothing I ran into in my brief spell with Ent Mon. Seeing as though you need a support agreement to use Enterprise Monitor you should raise a ticket with Oracle for further debugging.

Answer (score 0):

There is really nothing you can do once a shutdown starts. Why ?

According to the [**MySQL Documentation on the Shutdown Process**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-shutdown.html)

> 2 The server creates a shutdown thread if necessary.
>
> Depending on how shutdown was initiated, the server might create a
>   thread to handle the shutdown process. If shutdown was requested by a
>   client, a shutdown thread is created. If shutdown is the result of
>   receiving a SIGTERM signal, the signal thread might handle shutdown
>   itself, or it might create a separate thread to do so. If the server
>   tries to create a shutdown thread and cannot (for example, if memory
>   is exhausted), it issues a diagnostic message that appears in the
>   error log:
>
> ```
> Error: Can't create thread to kill server
> ```
>
> 3 The server stops accepting new connections.
>
> To prevent new activity from being initiated during shutdown, the
>   server stops accepting new client connections by closing the handlers
>   for the network interfaces to which it normally listens for
>   connections: the TCP/IP port, the Unix socket file, the Windows named
>   pipe, and shared memory on Windows.

It sounds like you are past Stage 3 because you got `Connection refused: connect`

In addition, note what may have triggered Stage 2:

> If shutdown is the result of receiving a ***SIGTERM*** signal, the signal thread might handle shutdown itself, or it might create a separate thread to do so.

What could be that trigger ? Stage 1 says regarding Windows

> A server running as a service on Windows shuts down when the services manager tells it to.

At this point, you have most likely reached Stage 4, which would go on to terminate currently active connections.

## CONCLUSION

Maybe a Bug Report or Trouble Ticket would be in order. Just make sure you have done your due diligence in terms of finding out if the Service Manager died or that human error or lack of memory on the Windows box was ruled out.